# Force Anaconda to install tensorflow 1.14

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda, version

Now, the official TensorFlow on Anaconda is 2.0. My question is how to force Anaconda to install an earlier version of TensorFlow instead. So, for example, I would like Anaconda to install TensorFlow 1.14 as plenty of my projects are depending on this version.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can force installing a certain version of any package found on Anaconda using simply an `=` operator with the package version attached to it.

So, if you want to install tensorflow 1.14, you can run the following command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow=1.14
```

You can replace `1.14` with any other versions. To see the available versions of `tensorflow` on Anaconda, you can run:

```
conda search tensorflow
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/BuDBwA3F got a segmentation fault for this

Comment: I tried this command, it took **5 hours** and then failed. (error was about wrong Python version, and wrong glibc version). I then tried the process described by @sun and @brainslugs83 in the other answer (`conda create -n myenv -c conda-forge --strict-channel-priority python=3.6` ; `conda activate myenv` ; `conda install pip` ; `pip install tensorflow==1.14`) This took 15 minutes and succeeded. There was no need to install another version of Anaconda. (I had version 22.9.0)

Answer (score 3):

first find the python version of tensorflow==1.14.0, then find the Anaconda version by python version.

e.g. tensorflow 1.14.0 can work well on python36, and Anaconda 3.5.1 has python36. So install the Anaconda 3.5.1, then install tensorflow==1.14.0 by pip

Comment: This was the missing link for me -- I had to create an env with Python=3.6; and then I could run `pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow==1.14.0` -- Thanks!